# Electrical Charges

Tags: electrical-engineering, materials, manufacturing-engineering

I have been doing some research on different textile materials and electrical charges. If I wanted to change a negatively charged material to a positive one, would that be possible? Thinking I could by adding some positively charged material into the fibers?  Has anyone dabbled in this before to give me some ideas?  What type of engineer would one go to for help on this aspect of research/creation? An electrical engineer?

Comment: the problem relates to physics, possibly to chemistry

Comment: Thank you! Will look into those avenues

Comment: You need to explain a bit about this business of change.  Do you simply wish to discharge and charge a material like what happens for static electricity? If you just want to change material, you will just need to look at the minimum amount of energy required just to eject an electron from a  body for each material.  One that loses electrons with less work will tend to turn positive, unless rubbed with a material that requires even less work.

Comment: Here's a starting point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function

Comment: Thank you Abel, ultimately the goal would be to charge and discharge like static electricity but not sure if that is possible to keep the charge, thinking it would be possible if I changed the material ejecting an electron?